# Where to put php files for security

Tags: php, security, iis

I am adding a php program file to my web site and put it in my bin directory on a Windows Server.  My ISP tech said the program wouldn't work there because it is hidden from the public.  So I put it in my root directory and it worked.  However, is it secure to put a php file in the root directory of a server running Windows IIS?  If not, how do I protect it without having to remove the hidden security on my bin directory?

Comment: If your file contains configuration information then placing in the bin folder is the right thing to do as you don't want people to view the file. But if the file outputs html then the bin folder is not the place for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as jeff commented, `action` files have to be in the documentroot [or subdirectories]
any library/config/class.. can be out of public reach in bin or sub-documentroot.

example

```
/index.php
<?php include "../safer.php;" ?>
```

Comment: I have my php file in a subdirectory under my root directory.  In this php file I have an include for the php file that contains my sql connection parameters.  However, my sql commands are in the main php file.  Is this considered safe?  Or are you suggesting I put all my logic in the include file and just use the main php file as a repository for the include file?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.  I just put an include to a php file in the bin directory in my main php file.  All the logic is in the bin directory php file and it works great.